# Error on creating NSString of url

Tags: ios, gps, wcf-rest

I want to send my gps data from my iphone/ipad using restful service, but i am getting error

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException reason: unrecognized selector sent to
>   class'

I am getting error on following code..

```
 [NSString stringwithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.105/TestServices/Service2.svc/gpsdata?latitude=%f&longitude=%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capitalization is incorrect, it should be stringWithFormat!

Comment: Thanks, real shame that i was not able to figure out my self

Comment: That's one downside of Objective-C, you don't get a compile-time error when something like this happens!

Comment: @Clafou:  You do get a compile time warning though.